# How to access object's array value in interpolation?

Tags: angular, angular8

This is my json data:

[image]

I want to access marked key (`fundAllocated`) in interpolation but I am not able to access it. It is in `schemeFunds` array. How can I access it?

This is what I tried:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="financialManagementData && financialManagementData.length">
  <tr *ngFor="let fManagement of financialManagementData">
    <td>{{fManagement.name}}</td>
    <td>
      <ng-container *ngIf = "fManagement['selectedScheme']; else showFundAmount; 
       let i = index">
        <div class="form-group mb-0">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control fund-amount height-30"
              [(ngModel)]="fManagement.fundAmount" name="fundAmount">
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm color-white mb-0" 
              (click)="fManagement['selectedScheme'] = 
              fManagement['selectedScheme'];">
                Save
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #showFundAmount>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div class="fund-amount">
            {{fManagement['schemeFunds']['fundAllocated']}}
          </div>
          <span class="text-primary f_16 c_p">
            <i class="fas fa-edit" (click)="fManagement['selectedScheme'] = ! 
            fManagement['selectedScheme']; checkIsEditable(fManagement)"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </td>
    <td>{{fManagement.fundUtilized}}</td>
    <td>{{fManagement.balance}}</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm color-white mb-0" 
      (click)="createTransaction(fManagement)">
        Create Transaction
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: fManagement['schemeFunds'][0]['fundAllocated'] - you have missed array index. if you want to loop over more than one array item. you might need to use ngfor again to loop over the items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to have an additional `*ngFor` loop specifically for the `schemeFunds` array

```html
<ng-template #showFundAmount>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let amount of fManagement['schemeFunds']">
      <div class="fund-amount">{{amount['fundAllocated']}}</div>
    </ng-container>
    <span class="text-primary f_16 c_p">
      <i class="fas fa-edit"
        (click)="fManagement['selectedScheme'] = ! fManagement['selectedScheme']; checkIsEditable(fManagement)"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Or if you're sure the `schemeFunds` array will always only have a single element, you could access the 0th element of the array directly.

```html
<ng-template #showFundAmount>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="fund-amount">{{fManagement['schemeFunds'][0]['fundAllocated']}}</div>           <!-- element at 0th position -->
    <span class="text-primary f_16 c_p">
      <i class="fas fa-edit"
        (click)="fManagement['selectedScheme'] = ! fManagement['selectedScheme']; checkIsEditable(fManagement)"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

BTW if case 2 applies, you need to adjust it in the backend to send the `schemeFunds` as an object instead of an array with a single element. Then you could access the `fundAllocated` directly without the array key: `fManagement['schemeFunds']['fundAllocated']`

#### Show 0 if `fundAllocated` isn't available

You could just append an OR in the interpolation expression to show 0 if the property isn't available.

```html
<div class="fund-amount">{{fManagement['schemeFunds'][0]['fundAllocated'] || 0}}</div>
```

Comment: What if i want to show 0 for other records whose for which fundAllocated is not available?

Comment: and now it's not showing in above ngModel which is editable. Value is not patched

Comment: For the first question, you could append an OR to the end of the expression. I've updated the answer. For the second question, you're binding to the `fManagement.fundAmount` which isn't any way related to the `fManagement['schemeFunds'][0]['fundAllocated']` property. What do wish to show in the input field?

Comment: @aashu1807: Yes but which value do you want to bind? The `fManagement['schemeFunds'][0]['fundAllocated']` property?

Comment: can you please check the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get property directly even though it is a property of an array element.

So instead of doing this `fManagement['schemeFunds']['fundAllocated']` it should actually be `fManagement['schemeFunds'][0]['fundAllocated']`.
It takes **schemeFunds** element (which contains an array), selects first array element (index 0) and takes property **fundAllocated** of that element.

Edit:
Most probably you'll need to iterate through array with ngFor and display the intended information for each element in schemeFunds array.

Answer (score 0):

**One more thing to notice in your code,** you need to pass context to the ng-template `#showFundAmount`, currently it has no access to fManagement.

`*ngIf = "fManagement['selectedScheme']; else showFundAmount; let i = index"`

becomes

`*ngIf = "fManagement['selectedScheme']; else showFundAmount;context : { $implicit : fManagement }; let i = index; "`

and your ng-template becomes  :

```
<ng-template #showFundAmount let fManagement>
```